Consistent Warning I/O "error: The client supported protocol versions [TLSv1.3] are not accepted by server preferences [TLS12] warning"
We are trying to install the WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 to our production environment, but in the logs we see the following warning
TID: [] [] [2024-06-14 11:53:21,686]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - I/O error: The client supported protocol versions [TLSv1.3] are not accepted by server preferences [TLS12]
The warning appears in vanilla installation as well
We are using jdk 17.0.
Moreover, when we try to call a https client via the API Manager and the corresponding endpoint the call fails with the following error :
TID: [] [] [2024-06-14 10:12:18,858]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} - ERROR_CODE = 101500, STATE_DESCRIPTION = Exception occurred when Server establishing a connection to the backend, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_READY, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = I/O exception : Received fatal alert: protocol_version, TARGET_HOST = xxxx, TARGET_PORT = 8201, TARGET_CONTEXT =
https://xxxxxxxxx:8201/cpeManager-ws/cpeInfo?caller=CGN&jobId=gkcpe11&cli=2103333333
, HTTP_METHOD = GET, TRIGGER_TYPE = api, TRIGGER_NAME = CpeManager-WS:vv1, REMOTE_ADDRESS = xxxxx.xxxx.gr/xxxxxxxx:8201, CONNECTION = http-outgoing-5
TID: [] [] [2024-06-14 10:12:18,858] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} - I/O error: Received fatal alert: protocol_version javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
We have installed the certificate of the client to the java cacerts
Can you please help?
Thanks in advance

install WSO2 in a production environment
Create a proxy service in API-M with https client and endpoint


According to the error, the issue could  be that the client you are using to call the API deployed in API Manager uses TLS v1.3 but the server only supports v1.2. You can try changing the supported TLS versions of APIM by following the guide on the official documentation [1].
[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-transport-level-security/#configuring-passthrough-transport-level-ciphers-and-tls-versions
